# Does spark standalone cluster supports deploye mode = cluster for python applications?

Tags: apache-spark

I was going through the spark guide 2.1.0 and saw the following line 
on  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
Currently, standalone mode does not support cluster mode for Python applications.

But below that they have an example 
 Run on a Spark standalone cluster in cluster deploy mode with supervise

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

now i am confused... at one point they are saying that cluster mode is not supported for spark standalone cluster for python application but on the other hand they have given an example where they have deploye-mode = cluster for python application with spark standalone cluster
can anyone correct me if my interpretation is wrong ??

Comment: Yes it supports. `--deploy-mode` is specific to driver location only. It does not impacts for languages and cluster managers. [check this post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spark-yarn-concept-understanding-srinivas-reddy-alluri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html),

> **standalone mode** does not support cluster mode for Python applications.

and

> For **Python applications**, simply pass a .py file in the place of  instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py files to the search path with --py-files.

The example you posted in question is for a scala application . The example for python is given the document itself.

```
# Run a Python application on a Spark standalone cluster
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  examples/src/main/python/pi.py \
  1000
```